# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'kitchen'

Tags: python-3.4

when i run this code i get this error  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'kitchen'

i am very new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
st1 = []

number = 0

room_type =0

walls=0

print ("welcome to our painting cost estimate calculator")
print ("please enter the following information")


customer_number = input("please enter your telefone number")


date = input("please enter the date of the estimate \n(in short form)")

num_rooms = input("please enter the number of rooms that you wish to be painted")                 
int(num_rooms)

while int(room_type) < int(num_rooms):
    room_type = input("please enter the room name")
    list1.append(room_type))

    while int(walls)< int(room_type):
        wall = input ("enter the nmber of walls in",room_type,) 
        list1.append (float(2,wall))



wallpaper = input("does wallpaper need to be removed (y/n)\nthis costs £70")
if wallpaper == ("y"):
    Total_price + 70*(num_rooms)
if wallpaper == ("n"):
    measurements()

def measurements():
    measure = input("please enter the dementions for",room_type,"as follows   Height/width")
    list1.insert(2,measure)
```

Comment: Well what exactly do you expect it to do when you try to convert `'kitchen'` to an integer?!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `int()` on a string. This happens in the line

```
while int(walls)< int(room_type):
```

Comment: Well you *can* call `int` with a string, but unless it's a representation of an integer (`'123'`, `'10101'`, etc.) you shouldn't expect it to be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

As I had a lost moment:

```
def getrooms(wall_paper_removal_cost, cost_per_square_meter_paint):
    num_rooms = input('please input the number of rooms you like to paint:')
    rooms = []
    for i in range(1, int(num_rooms) + 1):
        print ()
        print ('for room number ' + str(i) + ':')
        room_name = input('what is the name of the room:')
        walls = int(input('how many walls need to be painted:'))
        paper = int(input('how many walls need wall paper removed:'))
        paper_cost = paper * wall_paper_removal_cost
        paint_cost = 0
        for t in range(1, walls + 1):
            print ('for room ' + room_name + ' wall ' + str(t) + ':')
            height = int(input('what is the height in meters:'))
            width = int (input('what is the width in meters:'))
            paint_cost += height * width * cost_per_square_meter_paint
        rooms.append([room_name, walls, paper, paper_cost, paint_cost])
    return rooms

def printcost(rooms):
    # alignment of printing need to be done properly
    # probably using ''.ljust() and ''.rjust() to make it look good
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, len(rooms)):
        print()
        print ('Room:' + rooms[i][0])
        print ('  Number of walls to be painted: ' + str(rooms[i][1]))
        print ('                                 cost:    ' + str(rooms[i][4]))
        print ('  Number of wallpaper removal  : ' + str(rooms[i][2]))
        print ('                                 cost:    ' + str(rooms[i][3]))
        total += rooms[i][3] + rooms[i][4]
    print ('===================================================================')
    print ('                                  total: ' + str(total))


def main():

    # set your costs for calculation
    cost_per_square_meter_paint = 12
    wall_paper_removal_cost = 70

    # get the details of each room
    rooms = getrooms(wall_paper_removal_cost, cost_per_square_meter_paint)

    #print out the estimate
    printcost(rooms)

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```